# Reordering of HTML Elements in Responsive Views

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

One thing that I keep running into with desktop vs. mobile comps from designers is reordering of HTML elements. My pages have to work across all breakpoints, so the text wraps/expands as the browser is resized (so heights of everything is always variable).

Here are some scenarios: (the pipes represent a float or column)

> Desktop:
>
> item 1 | item 2 item 3
>
> Mobile:
>
> item 3 item 1 item 2
>
> Desktop:
>
> li
>
> -- content
>
> Mobile
>
> li
>
> -- keep background image
>
> -- show the content of the li beneath the background image (so basically outside the LI) with a white bg

What is the best way (if any) to reorder HTML elements across various breakpoints using fluid layouts? It seems like using JavaScript to listen for window resize is overkill and absolute positioning doesn't work when multiple elements have to be re-arranged.

If anyone knows of a solution, it would be great if you could post it on JSFiddle.

Comment: What have you tried?  The first thing that comes to mind is using CSS `@media` and using class definitions for each item and then `floating` and stacking the items as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of using a combination of `float` and `position: absolute`.

http://jsfiddle.net/qmWwp/

**HTML**

```
<div class="group" id="wrapper">
    <div class="content" id="item1">ITEM 1</div>
    <div class="content" id="item2">ITEM 2</div>
    <div class="content" id="item3">ITEM 3</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper {
    width: 927px;
}
.content {
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #000000;
    border: 5px solid red;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
@media all and (min-width: 800px) {
    #item1 {
        float: left;
    }
    #item2 {
        float: left;
    }
    #item3 {
        float: left;
    }
}
@media all and (max-width: 799px) {
    .content {
        position: absolute;
    }
    #item1 {
        top: 8px;
        left: 315px;
    }
    #item2 {
        top: 8px;
        left: 624px;
    }
    #item3 {
        float: left;
    }
}
.group:after {
    content:"";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

As mentioned in other answers, full control is not available with `float` but using `position: absolute` you have more control.  Now you may run into issues if you need perfect spacing to the pixel, especially if the container has text, as different browsers will render the text slight different, typically throwing CSS off by a single pixel.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add break points `@media` for sure plus you need to check for

```
@media
{
li:nth-child(item1) { float: ....}
li:nth-child(item2) 
li:nth-child(item3) 
}
```

or you can also use jQuery to dynamically move the `div`s as shown below:

```
$("<li>item 1</li>").insertAfter($("classname").children()[2]);
```